# Log shell stdin & stdout

Tags: linux, bash, logging, shell

I'm trying to setup a bastion that I would like to log all commands executed and output to (ideally per-user) log files.

I looked at auditd, and can see how to log commands executed to system I don't capture commands executed on secondary systems from ssh connections outbound from the bastion.

eg.

```
Desktop# ssh bastion.corp
Bastion# ssh switch1.corp
sw1# show run
<stuff>
```

with auditd I just get told ssh switch1.corp was executed, not the show run command on the remote system.

Answer (score 0):

try rootsh package in Linux.
just setup a server, as your ssh-server and ask your users to authenticate to this server fist, in order to connect other devices.you may use access-list or any other filtering mechanism to limit your systems or devices to get logged in, only from your ssh server.
this package, logs all the commands entered by the user, and all the results returned to the screen, in text.